# Cucumber Reports not generated on jenkins job

Tags: protractor, cucumber, report, reporting, cucumberjs

So I upgraded my protractor to version 5.3.0 and since than cucumber reports are not generated. I suspect it is version mismatch issue but i'm not sure. I've tried some of versions of cucumber but it doesn't help. Can anyone shed some light on possible issues ?

Here are the versions of various cucumber packages i'm using.

```
    "cucumber": "4.2.1",
    "cucumber-html-report": "0.2.5",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^4.0.4",
    "cucumber-junit": "1.5.0",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^1.4.4",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-execute": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "~5.0.0",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "~0.2.5",
    "grunt-shell-spawn": "~0.3.10",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.1",
    "node-minify": "~2.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.0.0",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "~0.0.21",
    "protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin": "~1.0.2",
    "proui-utils": "^1.1.88",
    "rally": "~2.1.2",
    "request": "~2.85.0",
```

This is the exact error which i'm getting.

```
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: None report file was added!
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:60)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:324)
at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:248)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Furthure more in console this is what jenkins try to do.

```
  [CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 4.4.0
  [CucumberReport] JSON report directory is ""
  [CucumberReport] Copied 1570 json files from workspace             
  "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/IQP_JOBS/proui_scripts" to reports directory 
  "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/IQP_JOBS/jobs/proui_scripts/builds/108/cucumber-html-reports/.cache"
  [CucumberReport] Copied 2 properties files from workspace       
  "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/IQP_JOBS/proui_scripts" to reports directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/IQP_JOBS/jobs/proui_scripts/builds/108/cucumber-html-reports/.cache"
  [CucumberReport] Processing 0 json files:
  [CucumberReport] Missing report result - report was not successfully completed
  [CucumberReport] Build status is left unchanged
```

Comment: I am facing exact same issue except I am using cucumber directly and not with protractor but cucumber.json file is not getting generated in jenkins workspace and as a result jenkins-cucumber plugin not able to create html report out of it. It was working fine few days back not able to understand what has changed but same error as urs. were u able to get the solution to this?